# Embed the Klein bottle into the 3-manifold $S^{2} \times S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, klein-bottle

Can the Klein bottle $K$ be embedded into $S^{2} \times S^{1}$?

If so, how does it work? If not, what is the obstruction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this different from is $S^3 = S^2 \times S^1$?

Comment: Not! Fundamental groups are different.

Comment: The best I can do is to embed  it into $RP^{2} \times S^{1}$.

Comment: Or an 3-manifold with a free $S^{1}$-action. However there are two double orbits. The quotient space is $S^{2}$ in the orbifold sense.

Comment: can you embed a 3-manifold into a Klein bottle?

Comment: @JonMarkPerry, the Klein bottle is a 2-manifold. You certainly can't embed a 3-manifold in a 2-manifold.

Comment: No. Klein bottle is 2-dimesion.

Comment: Thanks, John. That's great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Klein bottle can be given by $S^1 \times [0,2\pi] $ with the identificition

$$(\theta, 0) \sim (-\theta, 2\pi)$$

(where I used $\theta$ to parametrizes the circle). Now define

$$S^1 \times [0,2\pi] \to S^2 \times S^1, \ f(\theta, t)  =\big( a(\theta, t), e^{it} \big),$$

where

$$a(\theta, t ) = \sin\theta (\cos\frac{t}{2} , \sin \frac{t}{2}, 0)+ \cos \theta (0,0,1).$$

Note that

$$f(-\theta, 2\pi) = (a(-\theta, 2\pi ), e^{i2\pi}) = (a(-\theta, 2\pi ), e^{i0}) $$

and

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
a(-\theta, 2\pi ) &=\sin(-\theta) (\cos \pi , \sin \pi, 0)+ \cos (-\theta) (0,0,1)\\
&= \sin \theta (\cos 0 , \sin 0, 0)+ \cos \theta (0,0,1) \\
&= a(\theta, 0)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus $f(\theta, 0) = f(-\theta, 2\pi)$ and so $f$ descends to a map

$$\tilde f: K  \to  S^2 \times S^1. $$

Note that $\tilde f$ is injective.

Comment: (I haven't read your answer, so can't say anything about whether or not I agree with your construction.) I don't see how this answer is contradicted by Joel's; $H_1(S^1 \times S^2; \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z) = \Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Ar ha!! I dunno why I was thinking about $S^3$ all the time (probably by some weird comment by someone below the question) Thanks. @MikeMiller

Answer (score 4):

The Klein bottle is the space $S^1 \times I/\sim$, where the equivalence relation identifies $(z,0) \sim (\bar z, 1)$, where $\bar z$ denotes complex conjugation (aka reflection across the x-axis).

Denote by $\text{rot}_\theta$ the rotation of 3-space which moves the z-axis down theta degrees toward the y-axis (this is a rotation whose fixed set is the x-axis). Write $g: S^1 \to S^2$ for the standard inclusion of the equator.

$f: S^1 \times I \to S^1 \times S^2$, given by $f(z,t) =(2\pi t, \text{rot}_{\pi t} g(z))$ descends to an embedding of the Klein bottle.