# How to find an embedding of the Klein bottle into $S^{1}$ $\times$ $S^{2}$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, geometric-topology, klein-bottle

This is from an intro topology course. How can I go about finding an explicit embedding for the Klein bottle in this situation?

Comment: Edit: my argument that there is no such embedding was wrong. My error was assuming that the $(S^1\times S^2,S^1\times S^2\setminus K)$ is what Hatcher calls a "good pair." See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1202356/embedd-the-klein-bottle-into-a-3-manifold?rq=1